# How to make it this display in a new line

Tags: jquery

I am getting a response from backend this way

```
{
    "toppings": [
        {
            "name": "Quantity1",
            "value": [
                "HoneywithChocolateSauce10ML",
                "HoneywithCarmel20ML",
                "HoneywithCarmel10ML"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and i am parsing it in the below manner and forming the HTML dynamically

```
else if(toppins.length >= 0)
{
var uitaghtml = '<ul>';
for (var d = 0; d < toppins.length; d++) {
 var uitaghtml = '<ul>' +
             '<li>' + toppins[d].value + '</li>' +
            '</ul>';

itemcart ='<div class="order-listdetails-wrap"> 
                    <div class="orderTitle">'+itemname+'</div> 
                    <div class="orderCont"> 
                        <div class="img"><img src="'+image+'"/></div> 
                        <div class="orderPrice"> 
                            <p>Qty: <span>1</span></p> 
                             ' + uitaghtml + '</ul> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>';


                divhtml.append(itemcart);
    }
}
```

With the above the HTML is displaying this way

Instead of comma seperated values , how to make that display one after another ??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing out the `value` property of your data, but that property's an array. You should iterate over it instead. I've done it here using jQuery:

```
var uitaghtml = '<ul>';
$.each(toppins[d].value, function(i, text) { 
     uitaghtml += "<li>" + text + "</li>";
});
uitaghtml += "</ul>";
```

You may also like to consider using a JavaScript templating library like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to help you get your HTML out of your source code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the values:

```
for (var d = 0; d < toppins.length; d++) {
    var uitaghtml = '<ul>';
    for (var v = 0; v < toppins[d].value.length; v++) {
        uitaghtml += '<li>' + toppins[d].value[v] + '</li>' +
    }
    uitaghtml += '</ul>';

    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var x={
"toppings": [
    {
        "name": "Quantity1",
        "value": [
            "HoneywithChocolateSauce10ML",
            "HoneywithCarmel20ML",
            "HoneywithCarmel10ML"
        ]
    }
]
};


 $.each(x.toppings[0].value,function(i,v){
      var uitaghtml = '<li>' + v + '</li>';
     console.log(uitaghtml);
 });
```